# Get field value using cakephp magic function

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to find a user detail using cakephp magic function like that

```
$this->User->findById($id);
$this->User->findByName($name);
```

this works properly, but i want to find user detail using their quote

```
$this->User->findByQuote($quote);
```

But there are some problem occuring...
DB field name => quote

Comment: Can you let us know what are those problems?

Comment: it returns an empty array

Comment: have you checked the sql query?

Comment: What is the type of the `quote` column? And what is `$quote`?

Comment: Its varchar type column and contains user quotation info

Comment: @mcgowan.b yes, i've checked query

Comment: @KrishnaGupta Could you edit your question and add the resulting query?

Comment: If you could tell us the resulting query that would help.

Comment: Have you run the query generated directly against your database to check it returns something?